# I am trying to use argpase module in following snippet

Tags: python, argparse, motion-detection

This code:

```py
from imutils.video import VideoStream      
import argparse                           
import datetime                            
import imutils                             
import time
import cv2    


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="Path of video file" )
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type==int, default=500, help="Minimum area size")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Produces this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "f:\projects c,c++,python\python\motion detection.py", line 12, in 
> ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type==int, default=500, help="Minimum area size")
> File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1402, in add_argument
> kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Aditya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\argparse.py", line 1532, in _get_optional_kwargs
> if not option_string[0] in self.prefix_chars:
> TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `type==int` has too many `=` signs.

Answer (score 1):

Please use ` so your code is easier to read.

The problem is `type==int`, that's a boolean check so you're actually passing `True` or `False` as an argument. Just replace it with `type=int` and you're good to go.